# Get a parents + children tree with pg-promise

Tags: javascript, postgresql, pg-promise

I use the `pg-promise` library with `bluebird` for making dependent queries.
I have two tables, a and b, looking like this:

```
|   a   |     |   b   |  
|-------|     |-------|
| a_id  |     | b_id  |
| prop1 |     | prop2 |
              |  b_a  |
```

where `b.b_a` is a reference to `a.a_id`. I want to select all entries matching a given `prop1` and the result should contain all matching `a`-rows plus the corresponding `b`-rows for each `a`. This should be doable with two dependent queries. Both queries may return multiple results.

If table `a` only returns one row I can do this:

```
function getResult(prop1) {
    return db.task(function (t) {
        return t.one("select * from a where prop1=$1", prop1)
            .then(function (a) {
                return t.batch([a, t.any("select * from b where b_a=$1", a.a_id)]);
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                var a = data[0];
                var bs = data[1];
                bs.forEach(function (b) {
                    b.a = a;
                });
                return bs;
            });
    });
}
```

And I'm also able to get all matching `b`-entries for multiple `a`-results like this:

```
function getResult(prop1) {
    return db.task(function (t) {
        return t.many("select * from a where prop1=$1", prop1)
            .then(function (as) {
                var queries = [];
                as.forEach(function (a) {
                    queries.push(t.any("select * from b where b_a=$1", a.id));
                });
                return t.batch(queries); // could concat queries with as here, but there wouldn't be a reference which b row belongs to which a row
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                // data[n] contains all matching b rows
            });
    });
}
```

But how to bring those two together?

Comment: They're in the same order, right? So just access `as[n]` together with `data[n]`. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572) on how to access `as`.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that might help. But there is a one to many relationship between `a` and `b`, so the indizes are not helpful here..

Comment: What's the return value of `batch`? Isn't `data` a two-dimensional array of some kind?

Comment: Just seen that it's multi-dimensional a second before I read your comment.. thanks a lot for that, could have seen that earlier!

Comment: `where a.a_b is a reference` - there is no `a_b` in table `a`.

Comment: `the result should contain all matching a-rows plus the corresponding b-rows for each a.` do you want a single object with the tree or an array of some sort? Not clear exactly what type of output you want.

Comment: @Krxldfx I have posted an answer for you below ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

---

When you have 2 tables: `Parent` -> `Child` with 1-to-many relationship, and you want to get an array of matching `Parent` rows, each row extended with property `children` set to an array of the corresponding rows from table `Child` ...

There are several ways to accomplish this, as the combination of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) and promises in general is very flexible. Here's the shortest version:

```
db.task(t => {
    return t.map('SELECT * FROM Parent WHERE prop1 = $1', [prop1], parent => {
        return t.any('SELECT * FROM Child WHERE parentId = $1', parent.id)
            .then(children => {
                parent.children = children;
                return parent;
            });
    }).then(a => t.batch(a))
})
    .then(data => {
        /* data = the complete tree */
    });
```

This is what we do there:

First, we query for `Parent` items, then we map each row into a query for the corresponding `Child` items, which then sets its rows into the `Parent` and returns it. Then we use method [batch](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Task.html#batch) to resolve the array of `Child` queries returned from method [map](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#map).

#### UPDATE for ES7

Here's the same as above, but using ES7 `async`/`await` syntax:

```js
await db.task(async t => {
    const parents = await t.any('SELECT * FROM Parent WHERE prop1 = $1', [prop1]);
    for(const p of parents) {
        p.children = await t.any('SELECT * FROM Child WHERE parentId = $1', [p.id]);
    }
    return parents;
});
// the task resolves with the correct data tree
```

---

The task will resolve with an array like this:

```
[
    {
        "parent1-prop1", "parent1-prop2",
        "children": [
            {"child1-prop1", "child1-prop2"},
            {"child2-prop1", "child2-prop2"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "parent2-prop1", "parent2-prop2",
        "children": [
            {"child3-prop1", "child3-prop2"},
            {"child4-prop1", "child4-prop2"}
        ]
    }    
]
```

API references: [map](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#map), [batch](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Task.html#batch)

**UPDATE**

See a better answer to this: [JOIN table as array of results with PostgreSQL/NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805736/get-join-table-as-array-of-results-with-postgresql-nodejs).

Comment: Thanks a lot, `map` is very helpful here - I somehow didn't find that myself.

Comment: @Krxldfx `map` is only a convenience method that makes your code shorter, but not strictly required to implement your task ;)

Comment: @Krxldfx Updated with a link to a better/fuller answer ;)

Comment: Added ES7 example.