# Conditional task with pg-promise

Tags: javascript, promise, pg-promise

I am trying to simply read a value from a table and based on the return value call for additional queries and return the combined results.

let's take a simple example:
table `Users` has `id`, `name` and `emailid`
and let's say if `emailid` is not null we want to call the email table and return a results like `{ id:[id], name:[name], email:[email]}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest syntax supported by [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

```
db.task(t => {
    return t.map('SELECT * FROM Users', [], user => {
        return user.emailid ?
            t.one('SELECT * FROM Emails WHERE id = $1', user.emailid, e=> {
                user.email = e.email;
                return user;
            }) : user;
    }).then(t.batch);
})
    .then(data => {
        // success
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // error
    });
```

See the API: [Database.map](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#map), [Database.one](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#one).

See also a related question: [Get a parents + children tree with pg-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664258/get-a-parents-children-tree-with-pg-promise).

---

**NOTE:** A better approach would use a single query with `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I also agree, in the above case, left join is the way to go but my actual code is more complicated. Thanks!

Comment: @Parham I've realized I made one stupid mistake there, just corrected it, replacing `: null` with `: user`. Otherwise it was replacing each user who didn't have email with a `null` :)

Comment: Just as I came back to suggest a correction , I saw this comment! You are awesome man. Thanks !