# Nested query object mapping with pg-promise

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I'm going through an example from [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) for method [map](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.map):

```
// Build a list of active users, each with the list of user events:
db.task(t => {
    return t.map('SELECT id FROM Users WHERE status = $1', ['active'], user => {
        return t.any('SELECT * FROM Events WHERE userId = $1', user.id)
            .then(events=> {
                user.events = events;
                return user;
            });
    }).then(t.batch);
})
    .then(data => {
        // success
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // error
    });
```

Let's say the `Event` entity has a one to many relationship with e.g. `Cars`, and I want to list all the `cars` connected to each `event`, how can I use the [map](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.map) function when the object I want is more than one level deep?

The result I want could look something like this:

```
[{
    //This is a user
    id: 2,
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Doe",
    events: [{
        id: 4,
        type: 'type',
        cars: [{
            id: 4,
            brand: 'bmw'
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

---

```
function getUsers(t) {
    return t.map('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE status = $1', ['active'], user => {
        return t.map('SELECT * FROM Events WHERE userId = $1', user.id, event => {
            return t.any('SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE eventId = $1', event.id)
                .then(cars => {
                    event.cars = cars;
                    return event;
                });
        })
            .then(t.batch) // settles array of requests for Cars (for each event)
            .then(events => {
                user.events = events;
                return user;
            });
    }).then(t.batch); // settles array of requests for Events (for each user)
}
```

And then using it:

```
db.task(getUsers)
    .then(users => {
        // users = an object tree of users->events->cars
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // error
    });
```

Method [map](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#map) simplifies mapping retrieved rows into something else, and since we map them into promises, those need to be settled, for which we use method [batch](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Task.html#batch). We do it for each internal array of requests for `cars`, and then on the top level - to settle the array of requests for `events`.

**UPDATE**

It may be easier to read and maintain, if you do the tree logic upside down:

```
function getUsers(t) {
    const getCars = eventId => t.any('SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE eventId = $1', eventId);

    const getEvents = userId => t.map('SELECT * FROM Events WHERE userId = $1', userId, event => {
        return getCars(event.id)
            .then(cars => {
                event.cars = cars;
                return event;
            });
    }).then(t.batch);

    return t.map('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE status = $1', ['active'], user => {
        return getEvents(user.id)
            .then(events => {
                user.events = events;
                return user;
            });
    }).then(t.batch);
}
```

---

There is also a faster, single-query approach that can be found here:

- [get JOIN table as array of results with PostgreSQL/NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805736/get-join-table-as-array-of-results-with-postgresql-nodejs)