# Grab Sub Data with Sub Select in PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database that looks like this:

```
content
id     title      content
1      Home       Welcome to the homepage
```

-

```
fields
id    contentID   value
1     1           Field Value 1
2     1           Field Value 2
3     2           Field value in other content
```

I'm trying to write a query which combines the data for both and ultimately comes out with:

[
  {
    title: 'Home',
    content: 'Welcome to the homepage',
    fields: [
     {
       id: 1,
       contentID: 1,
       value: 'Field Value 1'
     },
     {
       id: 2,
       contentID: 1,
       value: 'Field Value 2'
     }
    ]
  }
]

Here is the query I tried, want to do it all in one query for performance:

```
let data = await query(`SELECT *, (SELECT array(SELECT * FROM stuff.fields WHERE stuff.fields.contentID=stuff.content.id)) as fields FROM stuff.content`);
```

Note that `stuff` is the schema name, I'm super new to PostgreSQL but I like it's data flexibility and speed compared to MySQL, and I don't think MySQL can do something like this.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805736/get-join-table-as-array-of-results-with-postgresql-nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected output looks like json. Use [jsonb functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
select to_jsonb(c)- 'id' || jsonb_build_object('fields', jsonb_agg(to_json(f)))
from content c
join fields f on c.id = f.content_id
group by c.id;
```

to get this json:

```
{
    "title": "Home",
    "fields": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "value": "Field Value 1",
            "content_id": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "value": "Field Value 2",
            "content_id": 1
        }
    ],
    "content": "Welcome to the homepage"
}
```

Comment: What would the full statement here be:
this is what I tried:
`SELECT to_jsonb(stuff.content)- 'id' || jsonb_build_object('fields', jsonb_agg(to_json(stuff.fields)))
FROM stuff.content
JOIN stuff.fields on stuff.content.id = "stuff"."fields"."contentID"
GROUP BY stuff.content.id` it says: missing FROM-clause entry for table "stuff"

Comment: Use table aliases like in the answer.