# pg-promise: what would be the best way to obtain multiple results sets where order matters

Tags: node.js, promise, pg-promise

here is my naive code:

```
db.projects.find_one(project_id, user_id)
        .then(project => {
            if (!project) {
                req.flash('info', 'Project not found');
                res.redirect('./projects');
            } else {
                db.codifier.get(project.project_id)
                    .then(codifier => {
                        codifier = build_codifier(codifier);
                        res.render('project', {project: project, codifier: codifier})
                    })

            }
        })
```

So basically, I want to get a single project, and if it is found - I want to gather some relative data, which is codifier, into separate result set, so I can render with {project: project, codifier: codifier}.

I know that nested .then statements seem bad... Is there a better way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: No, nested `then` statements are not necessarily bad, as long as you `return` them properly so that you can chain upon them. in your case - an asynchronous call in a condition - they're even quite unavoidable.

Comment: You can try the approach similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805736/get-join-table-as-array-of-results-with-postgresql-nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that nested .then statements seem bad... Is there a better way to do it? Thank you!

It is only bad because you do not re-use the database connection, requesting a new one for each query. You should use [tasks](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#tasks) to share the connection across queries.

See [Chaining Queries](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/chaining-queries).

Example of adding another method to your database repository class:

```
getCodifier(project_id, user_id) {
    // use the repository object object
    return this.db.task(t => {
        // you can access repository methods on the context here:
        return t.projects.find_one(project_id, user_id)
            .then(project => {
                if (project) {
                    return t.codifier.get(project.project_id)
                }
            });
    });
}
```

Or, if it is not reusable, you can do the task where it is needed instead.

Comment: Vitaly, how task can return multiple result sets?

Comment: @KonstantinRybakov A task returns whatever you return from its callback.

Comment: Thank you, Vitaly! The tasks did work and the code looks much better. And thanks for the excellent library!

Comment: @KonstantinRybakov I've added an example for your case.