# Nested query from postgresql and pg-promise

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I am trying retrieve nested query from postgres in node with pg-promise.

I was only able to retrieve simple non nested result with mixed data from tables.

I want to get from three tables (users, posts, comments) one dataset for each post - users.username, posts.text, post.timestamp, comments.author, comments.text, comments.timestamp. Users and posts are linked with username, posts and comments are linked with posts.id and comments.parrent.

This is data I want to get:

```
[
 {"username": "jane", 
 "postText": "Hello", 
  "postId": 4,
  "postTimestamp: "1651156414", 
  allComments: [
       {"commentsId": 2,
        "commentsAuthor": "john", 
        "commentsText": "nice", 
        "commentsTimestamp": "156454565456"
        }, 
       {"commentsId": 3,
        "commentsAuthor": "ghost",
       "commentsText": "hiii", 
       "commentsTimestamp": "165165848"}]
   }]
```

I am doing it with pg-promise:

```
function getUsers(t) {
    return t.map('SELECT * FROM posts', post=> {
        return t.map('SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.username = post.username', post.id, user => {
        return t.any('SELECT * FROM comments, posts WHERE comments.parrent = post.id', user.id)
        .then(comment => {
              user.comment = comment;
                return user;
                });
        })
            .then(t.batch) 
            .then(user=> {
              post.user = user;
                return post;
            });
    }).then(t.batch); 
}

db.task(getUsers)
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
        res.send(data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    });

});
```

It gives me error:

```
  TypeError: undefined is not a function at Array.map (<anonymous>) at obj.any.call.then.data
```

Do you have please any idea, what am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: The best advise - use JSON queries for such nested structures, with `json_build_object` function, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805736/get-join-table-as-array-of-results-with-postgresql-nodejs. The performance will be significantly higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is on this line:

```
return t.map('SELECT * FROM posts', post => {
```

which should be:

```
return t.map('SELECT * FROM posts', [], post => {
```

You are passing in a function as a formatting parameter, hence the problem.

But generally, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805736/get-join-table-as-array-of-results-with-postgresql-nodejs) gives a far superior solution, in terms of the performance, via JSON function `json_build_object`, as you will execute just one query, versus many as you are trying.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try also second solution you have mentioned.